# Do we really need clusterExport in parallel computing in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Do we really need clusterExport to put the data into different computing unit created by makeCluster?

So here is my case:

```
library(doParallel)
library(caret)
library(xgboost)
# cl <- makePSOCKcluster(5)  # this line or next line,you pick either should be fine
cl = makeCluster(5)
registerDoParallel(cl)
# clusterEvalQ(cl, c(library(caret),library(xgboost),library(dplyr)))
# clusterExport(cl, c("train_x",'y'),envir=environment())
## All subsequent models are then run in parallel
# model <- train(y ~ ., data = training, method = "rf")
classifier2 = train(form = diabetes~., 
                   data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2,
                   method = 'xgbTree',
                   metric = "ROC", # if custom summary function is used, the specific metric correspond to it should be used.
                   tuneGrid = grid,
                   na.action = na.exclude,
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                            number = 5,
                                            summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, 
                                            returnResamp="all",
                                            classProbs=T,
                                            savePredictions = T,
                                            verboseIter = TRUE))
```

This process can process smoothly without any bug.I don't even need to export data and load library into the clusters.
However,I am using parLapply before and without clusterExport the data, the program will stop in error.
But if the parallel is not running, the computing process is significantly speeding up. Before adding parallel is 300+ seconds and using parallel it is 100 seconds.

So how come the clusters gets the data? Is caret implement some strategy to load data itself?

Comment: Can't see you are doing parallel computing. You have only created the cluster, but not used it. Note that there is also `parallel::stopCluster` which shuts down the cluster when you don`t need it anymore. Suggest to read the [parallel package manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf).

Comment: Originally, I was thinking, but the performance improved must due to some actions I take and it is only parallel, and the answer here seems strengthen that, anyway, thanks for share your thoughts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you call `parallel::parLapply()` and likes, you need to make sure the parallel workers have access to all objects and functions needed.

However, in your case, you're calling `caret::train()`, which takes care of all that for you, so you should *not* use `clusterExport()` or `clusterEvalQ()` to set up the parallel workers.  If you do, **caret** would just redo the same thing again.  So, no, don't do it.  FWIW, it sounds like a mistake to believe it would be needed.  If you found such suggestions somewhere, please let them know it should *not* be done.

If you look at the source code for **caret**, you'll find that it parallelizes via `foreach()` with `%dopar%` of **foreach**. You'll also find that the **caret** developers declare what objects need to be exported via argument `.export` to `foreach()`.

Comment: Sure, and thank you very much for pointing my misunderstanding and the way to check the source code in the future when I have no one to ask. Appreciated!

Comment: Are you one of the author of the package of caret? Just curious:)

Comment: Nope, I'm not the author of **caret**. I'm the creator of Futureverse (www.futureverse.org/), which includes the **doFuture** package (https://dofuture.futureverse.org/). It can be used with **caret**, and I've done lots of validation towards **caret**, which led me to dive into the code (and also find bugs in **caret**).